# correctly formatting these user-agents

Tags: php, user-agent

I have a cache file with an array of user agents.

When i print each user agent out, this is what it looks like:

```
@^Mozilla/5\.0 \(.*Linux i686.*\) AppleWebKit/.* \(KHTML, like Gecko\).*Chrome/6\..*Safari/.*$@ 
@^Mozilla/5\.0 \(X11; U; Linux.*; .*; rv\:1\.9\..*\) Gecko/.* Firefox/.* Maemo Browser 1\.7\..*$@ 
@^Mozilla/5\.0 \(.*Linux i686.*\) AppleWebKit/.* \(KHTML, like Gecko\).*Chrome/7\..*Safari/.*$@ 
@^Mozilla/5\.0 \(.*Linux i686.*\) AppleWebKit/.* \(KHTML, like Gecko\).*Chrome/8\..*Safari/.*$@ 
@^Mozilla/5\.0 \(.*Linux i686.*\) AppleWebKit/.* \(KHTML, like Gecko\) .*Iron/6\..* Safari/.*$@ 
@^Mozilla/5\.0 \(.*Linux i686.*\) AppleWebKit/.* \(KHTML, like Gecko\) .*Iron/7\..* Safari/.*$@ 
@^Mozilla/5\.0 \(.*Linux i686.*\) AppleWebKit/.* \(KHTML, like Gecko\).*Chrome/9\..*Safari/.*$@ 

ect ect....
```

Now it looks like these user-agents have been escaped, so I've `stripslashes()` them.

I've also noticed some invalid characters here (`@`,`^`,`.*$@`), so I've `str_replaced()` them with nothing.

And the end result:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (.Linux i686.) AppleWebKit/. (KHTML, like Gecko).Chrome/6..Safari/ 
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux.; .; rv:1.9..) Gecko/. Firefox/. Maemo Browser 1.7. 
Mozilla/5.0 (.Linux i686.) AppleWebKit/. (KHTML, like Gecko).Chrome/7..Safari/ 
Mozilla/5.0 (.Linux i686.) AppleWebKit/. (KHTML, like Gecko).Chrome/8..Safari/ 
Mozilla/5.0 (.Linux i686.) AppleWebKit/. (KHTML, like Gecko) .Iron/6.. Safari/ 
Mozilla/5.0 (.Linux i686.) AppleWebKit/. (KHTML, like Gecko) .Iron/7.. Safari/ 
Mozilla/5.0 (.Linux i686.) AppleWebKit/. (KHTML, like Gecko).Chrome/9..Safari/
```

I'm planning to insert these user-agents into a database (already full of hundreds of thousands), and I'm worried they're still invalid in some way that I haven't noticed.

If I do insert these into the DB and they're invalid, I would then have to delete the whole DB, and start all over...

So I don't want to take any risks...

Can you guys spot anything wrong with these user-agent strings?

:)

Comment: List of Chrome UA strings: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/

Comment: This are all regular expressions of user agents. I assume, that every single of them covers multiple "real" agents at once. Don't know, what you want to achieve, but I assume, that "saving this as user agents" is not, what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), not invalid characters. If you simply match the strings against the user agent string, they will not match. They are meant to be matched as regular expressions.

Comment: I see. So how would I match the original user string with one of the regular expressions? or even better, how would I convert them into normal strings? (if possible)..Thanks ;)

Comment: You cannot convert them to simple strings, since the combinations are infinite. Take a look at [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match).

Comment: Right. So `preg_match` will match my `original` string with the regular expressions?

Comment: `preg_match()` will tell if you a certain regular expression matches a string.